# How to pagination in mysql table division

Tags: php, mysql

My question is how to handle pagination in Mysql table devision. I have a game admin management system to get player logins in a game log stored in a mysql database. The tables are divided by three months(quarter).

```
table_name_01_03
table_name_04_06
table_name_07_09
table_name_10_12
```

We're now is July so the table names are:

```
table_name_01_03
table_name_04_06
table_name
```

The fields of the tables are the same:

```
player_id        int             play id,&primary key
player_name      varchar         player name
last_login_time  datetime        last login time
```

Situation 1) If I want to get data by last login between 2015-07-01 00:00:00~2015-07-31 23:59:59, I just need to use sql like:

```
select * from table_name 
where last_login_time between '2015-07-01 00:00:00' and '2015-07-31 23:59:59' 
limit start_page,end_page;
```

Situation 2) If I want to get data by last login between 2015-01-01 00:00:00~2015-01-31 23:59:59 ,I just need to use sql like:

```
select * from table_name_01_03
where last_login_time between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-07-31     23:59:59' 
limit start_page,end_page;
```

So there are no problems in above situations.

=====================================================================

Situation 3) If I want to get data by last login between 2015-03-01 00:00:00~2015-04-30 23:59:59
some how I may use sql like:

```
select * from table_name_01_03 as a,table_name_04_06 as b
where 
(a.last_login_time between '2015-03-01 00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59')
and 
(b.last_login_time between '2015-04-01 00:00:00' and '2015-04-30 23:59:59')
limit start_page,end_page;
```

I have two questions for situation three:

**The table data rows of any one is more than 1.000.000, so the sql is really not a nice solution. Is there a better solution like the use of a temporary table?**

**I don't know how to combine the time conditions.**

=====================================================================

To carry out the sql solution,this is my code to get tables,so i wonder if the code can be improved.

```
$current = strtotime('2016-07-24 20:56:25');
$current = strtotime('2017-07-24 20:56:25');
$current_year = date('Y',$current);
$current_month = date('m',$current);
for ($i=0; $i <= $current_year-2015; $i++) { 
    $year = 2015+$i;
    $all_table_map = array(
        '1'=>$year.'_01_03',
        '2'=>$year.'_04_06',
        '3'=>$year.'_07_09',
        '4'=>$year.'_10_12',
    );
    foreach ($all_table_map as $key => $value) {
        if ($current_year==$year && $current_month < (($key-1)*3+1)) {
            array_pop($table_map[$year]);
            break;
        }
        $table_map[$year][$key] = $value;
    }
}
$month_map = array(
    '01'=>'1',
    '02'=>'1',
    '03'=>'1',
    '04'=>'2',
    '05'=>'2',
    '06'=>'2',
    '07'=>'3',
    '08'=>'3',
    '09'=>'3',
    '10'=>'4',
    '11'=>'4',
    '12'=>'4',
);
$current_quarter = $month_map[$current_month];
$table_name = 'table_name_'.$table_map[$current_year][$current_quarter]; 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($table_map);
```

Comment: Then click `edit` and fix it @MrSimpleMind ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It will help you greatly if you stop breaking your data into multiple tables, when it's the same data.

Comment: As @Jessica stated, breaking your tables up wasn't a great decision and makes this much more difficult. Your best solutions most likely involve schema changes.

Comment: Merge tables (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html) may also help you here, although dynamically defining them is tricky.

Comment: @Jessica  so are there any other solutions to deal with big data?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly UNION will make this better:

```
select * from 
    (select * from table_name_01_03 
    union
    select * from table_name_04_06) alltables
where last_login_time between '2015-03-01 00:00:00' and '2015-03-31 23:59:59'
limit start_page,end_page;
```

You can union as many tables as you want here.

Date ranges are always inefficient as they prevent mysql using indexes that contain the date.

Comment: May this is a better one. But the table data rows of any one is more than 1.000.000,if I union many tables,I'm afraid of mysql servers will die.

Comment: 1mil rows is not that much, some clever set up of indexes may help and, as others have stated here, you might think of ditching the multiple tables idea.